# startActivity is always calling onDestroy on the original activity

Tags: android

When calling startActivity(Intent intent) from my activity, onDestroy() method is always being called on it, so I lose my state of fragments, etc...

My understanding is that onStop should be called, and onDestroy could or could not be called. But my experience is that the original activity is always being destroyed.

I understand that if I have an activity with a listView, with an adapter, etc... Android does not expect me to sve the state of the adapter simply because I push another activity on top of this one, right?

Am I correct? What could be triggering this behavior?

Thank you

Comment: Are you testing directly on a device? If so maybe you have checked option to always destroy activities?

Comment: I'm testing in a device, yes. Didn't know about that option! I'll check this right now.

Comment: On my Galaxy s2 its settings > developer options > down to bottom, Do not keep activities, maybe something similar on your device.

Comment: You got it! Can't believe I spent 1:30h trying to figure this out. If you answer the question I'll mark it as checked for you. Also, since activities can potentially still be destroyed, is it a good practice to still save the state (contents of an adapter, etc...)? Or "destroy" is mot likely not going to happen and worrying about this is pointless?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: If your data is critical to the user experience, then I would always save the state, but its a trade off between how much effort it takes and how much you p*$s the user off. You don't know what they have running so you won't know if their OS needs the resources your app is taking.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On some devices (Galaxy S2 etc.), there is a setting which can cause activities to be destroyed whilst debugging. You can find this in:

```
settings > developer options > go down to the bottom under apps section >
```

`Do not keep activities`

Uncheck this option, to stop activities always being destroyed when you leave them.

Comment: OMG, you definitely saved my day! I think it persists on nearly every Samsung device if it has a separate "Developer options" section.