# Lifecycle issue between activity and fragment

Tags: android

I encountered a problem on Nexus 9 .(System Version Android marshmallow)
On android system before Android marshmallow,  fragmentA callback onStop will be called, when activity state containing fragmentA is Stopped.  fragmentA callbacks onDestroyView, onDestroy and onDetach will be called when activity state containing fragmentA is Destroyed.
The processes was described in official [website](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle)

Recently, I found out that on android marshmallow fragmentA callbacks onStop, onDestroyView, onDestroy and onDetach will be called continuously when activity state containing fragmentA is Stopped.

Comment: I never found this issue before.Can you post some code so we can help you figure out what's wrong？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I finally solved this issue. The issue I post was not correct. When activity state is Stopped, fragment callback onStop will be called normally.
There was no problem. The issue above was caused by that activity called the onDestroy method when I opened the "Don't keep activities" option in Developer Options. The issue was solved at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664554/startactivity-is-always-calling-ondestroy-on-the-original-activity).